# How to hide process windows

Tags: c, windows

I have a program `Setup.exe`. This `Setup.exe` starts another process `Child.exe` and this child could also start another Process. So basically something like this:

```
- Setup.exe  
    - Child.exe
       - Grandchild.exe
    - Child2.exe
       - Grandchild.exe
```

I don't know exactly how many processes my original Setup.exe will start.

My question is: How can I hide all of these windows (GUI or simple cmd window) generated by these processes?

I defined following flags for `STARTUPINFO`:

```
    StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
```

but this would only hide the original Processes GUI. If this Process start another child process, then that one won't be hidden.

Thanks!